# Twilio function used in autopilot task should send SMS but returns "an application error has occured"

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

(2nd updated version after input - there is progress - thank you) I want to use a Twilio function to send a SMS during a call (to avoid to make a full external application).
The goal is to send a confirmation SMS at the end of an automated call (with Twilio autopilot).
If the user says the correct sentence ("I want a confirmation by SMS please"), autopilot launches the following tasks.

```
{
    "actions": [
        {
            "redirect": "https://my_domain_here.twil.io/my_url_here"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then my function has the following code :

```
    exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    var client = context.getTwilioClient();
/**to have some view on incoming request    */
    console.log("context : "+JSON.stringify(context));
    console.log("event : "+JSON.stringify(event));
//send the answer SMS
    console.log("sending SMS");
client.messages
  .create({
    body: 'test sms',
    from: '+32x_my_nbr_xx',
    to: '+32x_my_other_nbr_xx'//is hardcoded - just to test
  })
.then(message => console.log(message.sid))
.done();
//now create the Twiml to send back to autopilot the text to be spoken
    console.log("SMS sent, returning to autopilot");
    var action = {"actions": [{"say": "I understand that you want a confirmation. I will send you a summary by SMS. Goodbye" }]};
    callback(null, action);
}
```

But when I call and I say "I want a confirmation by SMS", then I hear 'I understand that you want a confirmation. I will send you a summary by SMS. Goodbye". But no SMS is sent.
When I look in the logs of autopilot, the correct intent was triggered. 
The log of the function contains nothing (just regular logs but not the Msgid)
Anybody an idea ?

I know it would work but is there really no way to avoid writing and maintaining a complete backend just to send this SMS ?
Thx in advance.

Comment: Can you add a catch block to the create() function to see if for some reason the call to send a message via the REST API is returning an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Twilio developer evangelist here.

The update that used the REST API should help, but I think the problem now is that you are returning from the function before the API request is complete. Rather than calling the `callback` after the promise resolution, you should call it within the promise `then` function.

Something like this:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  var client = context.getTwilioClient();
  /**to have some view on incoming request    */
  console.log('context : ' + JSON.stringify(context));
  console.log('event : ' + JSON.stringify(event));
  //send the answer SMS
  console.log('sending SMS');
  client.messages
    .create({
      body: 'test sms',
      from: '+32x_my_nbr_xx',
      to: '+32x_my_other_nbr_xx' //is hardcoded - just to test
    })
    .then(message => {
      console.log('SMS sent, returning to autopilot');
      var action = {
        actions: [
          {
            say:
              'I understand that you want a confirmation. I will send you a summary by SMS. Goodbye'
          }
        ]
      };
      callback(null, action);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I suspect that the request being made by Autopilot is a Voice request which means you won't be able to return a MessageResponse since that only work for requests coming from an incoming SMS message.

To send the text in that Function you'll need to use the Node helper library to make a call to the REST API:

```
client.messages
  .create({
    body: 'This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?',
    from: '+15017122661',
    to: '+15558675310'
  })
.then(message => console.log(message.sid))
.done();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, indeed this is a voice request.I used your code but no SMS is sent. I hear also "an applicaiton error has occured. I adapt the post with the new code, which is already much better. Nb : the accounts are already used in production to send SMS through the same number so it should not be the problem. I also logged the value of the "client" before the operation and it contains the correct Account/token.